# How to make a html table like in the image

Tags: html

Can anyone help me how to accomplish a table like in the picture using html.

[image: The table]

This was my code so far

```html
<table border="1" align="right" width="200">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Umm...<br>yep.</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Umm...<br>yep.</td>
        <td>top right</td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td>bottom right</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Heres the image link https://ibb.co/rFgMB0k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your images table has 4 rows and 4 cols. some of `<td>` tags are expanded in rows, and some are expanded in cols. so it would be:

```html
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;    
}
</style>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4">Name</td>
    <td rowspan="4">Telephone</td>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Bill Gates</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```